# Rails how to get associated model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the method below which saves data to the users table as well as the user_details table.

When i pass the @newUser variable to the EmailMailer, i can't access the user_details attributes. How can i pass the user_details in the @newUser object without having to re-query the database?

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_details, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_details
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :login, :home_phone, :cell_phone, :work_phone, :birthday, :home_address, :work_address, :position, :company, :user_details_attributes
end

class UserDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :home_phone, :cell_phone, :work_phone, :birthday, :home_address, :work_address, :position, :company
end
```

Controller

```
# POST /users
def create
        @newUser = User.new(params[:user], :include =>:user_details)

        # create password
        require 'securerandom'
    password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)

        @newUser.password = password

        respond_to do |format|
            if @newUser.save

                @newUser.build_user_details
                # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome Email after save
                EmailMailer.welcome_email(@newUser).deliver
                # To be used in dev only. Just tests if the email was queued for sending.
                #assert ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?
                format.html {
                    flash[:success] = "User created successfully"
                    redirect_to(contacts_path)
                }
            else 
                format.html {
                    flash[:error] = flash[:error].to_a.concat resource.errors.full_messages
                    redirect_to(contacts_path)
                }
            end
        end
  end
```

Comment: @newuser is an instance variable you can treat the mailer like a view and use instance variables there just like you would in a view.

Comment: I know ryan, but i'm not sure how to get the user_details accessible to the @newUser instance variable.

Comment: @Catfish just for reference, you should not be sending emails inline like this. They should be moved to background processing. You can easily do this with DelayedJob or Resque. Inline email delivery like this will have a severe impact on your performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do what you are after.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_details
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_details
  after_initialize :build_user_details
  ...
end

# In controller
def create
  @new_user = User.new
  @new_user.attributes = params[:user]
  if @new_user.save
    # do mail thing
  else
    # other thing
  end
end
```

Comment: If i try this way, i'm getting the error `undefined method after_initialization`

Comment: Sorry. It is `after_initialze` not `after_initialization`. updated.

Comment: This seems to solve the current problem, but now i have another weird issue. I'll ask another question with it.

Comment: ok the true solution was to remove that "after_initialize" code, and use `@new_user = User.new
  @new_user.attributes = params[:user]` as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the UserDetails association prior to saving @newUser

```
@newUser.build_user_details
if @newUser.save
  #send mailer
else
  #do something else
end
```

Alternatively you could use the create action after the @newuser is saved

```
if @newUser.save
   @newUser.create_user_details
   #send mailer
else
   #do something else
end
```

By the way, Ruby/Rails convention is to use snake_case for variables. so @newUser should be @new_user.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that i tried your first solution and it didn't save my user_details to the database. I will try your second solution as i was unaware of `create_user_details`. Where are the methods `create_user_details` and `build_user_details` coming from?

Comment: Those methods are `method_missing` helpers given to you by the `has_one` relationship. The second solution will not save you a query though because it will result in two writes. The first solution should have worked fine. Alternatively, you could attach a life cycle method to user that initializes a `user_detail` object after `user` initialization.

Comment: With your first solution, if i put the `@newUser.build_user_details` after the `@newUser.save`, you can see that the user_details are being delete in this link - http://pastebin.com/fZ7zGimD. Why is that? if i completely remove the build_user_details line the user_details get saved.

Comment: The second solution seems to be doing the same thing

Comment: What values are you passing in as params to user_details table? Is it possible that you have validations that are preventing it from saving?

Comment: Here is example from a rake task I was running a few months ago. I know it's not the best way to do this but it might be helpful as an example.

Shelf_life has_one relationship with location.

ItemKind.last.shelf_lives.create
ItemKind.last.shelf_lives.last.create_location(:name => name)